# Capture button release in Android

Tags: android, button

Is it possible to capture release of a button just as we capture click using `onClickListener()` and `OnClick()` ?

I want to increase size of a button when it is pressed and move it back to the original size when the click is released. Can anyone help me how to do this?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You should set an OnTouchListener on your button.

```
button.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            increaseSize();
        } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            resetSize();
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: OnTouchListener listens only for touch right? I want to listen for click and release. How to go abt it?

Comment: A touch event down and up is practically a click. You could also set both an onclicklistener and an ontouchlistener on the button.

Comment: Just wondering why kiki got the accepted answer as I feel gave a more precise answer?

Comment: Your code should read `event.getAction()`, otherwise you'll get an incompatible operand types error. And I agree this should be the accepted answer, have an upvote :)

Comment: You should add event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL together MotionEvent.ACTION_UP. Looking in the documentation it says that ACTION_CANCEL must be handle as ACTION_UP. I mean: if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP || event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL)

Answer (score 4):

You have to handle MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL as well. So the code will be:

```
button.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP || 
            event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) {
            increaseSize();
        } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            resetSize();
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Didn't you mean to increase size on action DOWN, and reset on either UP or CANCEL?

Answer (score 2):

use an OnTouchListener or OnKeyListener instead.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to do this by overriding the `onKeyDown` and `onKeyUp`. These are both inherited from `android.widget.TextView`. Please see the [`android.widget.Button` doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html) for (a bit) more info.

Comment: onKeyDown and onKeyUp is for keyboard events if I am not wrong.Is is possible to capture click events for them?

Answer (score 0):

Eric Nordvik has the right answer except that

```
event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP
```

never got executed for me. Instead I did implement

```
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onClick(View v) {
            resetSize();      
    }
};
```

for the touch ACTION_UP.