# NullPointerException with view.getLocationOnScreen

Tags: java, android, android-widget

Very new to Android and have researched this for a while now but can't quite find the answer. I'm sure there's a simple solution.

I'm getting a `NullPointException` which is connected to my `View characterContainer = findViewById(R.id.icon_container);`

As I understand it, it seems I'm trying to implement it in the `onCreate()` method and as such the layout is not fully ready yet causing `characterContainer = null`.

So I need to use it in `onStart()` or `onResume()` but I'm struggling. This is my code so far:

```
package harvest.life.game;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class HarvestLifeActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        //find buttons on screen
        Button up = (Button)findViewById(R.id.up);
        up.setOnTouchListener(new UpListener());
        Button down = (Button)findViewById(R.id.down);
        down.setOnTouchListener(new UpListener()); // set as UpListener also for test reasons
        Button left = (Button)findViewById(R.id.left); 
        left.setOnTouchListener(new UpListener()); // set as UpListener also for test reasons
        Button right = (Button)findViewById(R.id.right);
        right.setOnTouchListener(new UpListener()); // set as UpListener also for test reasons
    }
    //what up button does 
    private final class UpListener implements OnTouchListener {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    //as long as up button is pressed it will keep moving character up
                    while (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                    {
                        View characterContainer = findViewById(R.id.icon_container);
                        Drawable walking = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.test_circle_red);
                        int startX = characterContainer.getLeft();
                        int startY = characterContainer.getTop();
                        int defaultWidth = characterContainer.getWidth();
                        int defaultHeight = characterContainer.getHeight();

                        //create new position for character 1 pixel closer to the top of screen
                        int newX = startX - 1;
                        int newY = startY;

                        //remove character
                        RelativeLayout view = (RelativeLayout) characterContainer;
                        ViewGroup owner = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
                        owner.removeView(view);

                        //re make character in new position created above and assign background as walking forwards animation
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams characParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(defaultWidth,defaultHeight);
                        characParams.leftMargin = newY;
                        characParams.topMargin = newX;
                        characterContainer.setLayoutParams(characParams);           
                        characterContainer.setBackgroundDrawable(walking); 
                    }
                    break;

                    // when button is let go of
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    RelativeLayout characterContainer = (RelativeLayout) 
                    findViewById(R.id.icon_container);
                    Drawable standing =
                        getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.test_circle);
                    //assign background back to standing animation
                    characterContainer.setBackgroundDrawable(standing);
                default:
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
    public void onResume() { // what goes here?

    }
}
```

Do I need to put a sort of function call in the `onResume` section or do I put the code for what the `OnTouchListener` does in here?

here's my main:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/game_container"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:background="#FFFFFF">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/side_bar_right"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="#000000">

    <ImageView
        android:contentDescription="@string/movement_button"
        android:id="@+id/up"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:src="@drawable/up" />

    <ImageView
        android:contentDescription="@string/movement_button"
        android:id="@+id/down"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:src="@drawable/down" />

    <ImageView
        android:contentDescription="@string/movement_button"
        android:id="@+id/right"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/right" />

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/side_bar_left"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
    android:background="#000000">

    <ImageView
        android:contentDescription="@string/movement_button"
        android:id="@+id/left"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/left" />     

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/icon_container"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="@drawable/test_circle"  >

</RelativeLayout >

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: To use the code in an onResume(), you simple do: `public void onResume(){super.onResume(); //your code}` However, I don't think that's what your problem is.

Comment: What line causes the exception?

Comment: Oh I just realized something: you define what the button does on click in the xml file, so those lines about onTouchListener are not needed. Like raju says, show us main.xml.

Comment: ah wonderful thanks for the quick response, I've editted my post to include main.xml

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I think you wanted:

```
package harvest.life.game;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class HarvestLifeActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        //find buttons on screen
        Button up = (Button)findViewById(R.id.up);
        //up.setOnTouchListener(new UpListener());
        Button down = (Button)findViewById(R.id.up);
        //down.setOnTouchListener(new UpListener());
        Button left = (Button)findViewById(R.id.up);
        //left.setOnTouchListener(new UpListener());
        Button right = (Button)findViewById(R.id.up);
        //right.setOnTouchListener(new UpListener()); 
    }

    public void onDownButtonClick(View view){
        while (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
        {

             View characterContainer = findViewById(R.id.icon_container);
             Drawable walking = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.test_circle_red);
             int startX = characterContainer.getLeft();
             int startY = characterContainer.getTop();
             int defaultWidth = characterContainer.getWidth();
             int defaultHeight = characterContainer.getHeight();

                 //create new position for character 1 pixel closer to the top of screen
                 int newX = startX - 1;
                 int newY = startY;

                 //remove character
                 RelativeLayout view = (RelativeLayout) characterContainer;
                 ViewGroup owner = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
                 owner.removeView(view);

                 //re make character in new position created above and assign background as walking forwards animation
                 RelativeLayout.LayoutParams characParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(defaultWidth,defaultHeight);
                 characParams.leftMargin = newY;
                 characParams.topMargin = newX;
                 characterContainer.setLayoutParams(characParams);           
                 characterContainer.setBackgroundDrawable(walking); 
                 }
    }

    public void onUpButtonClicked(View view){
        RelativeLayout characterContainer = (RelativeLayout) 
                findViewById(R.id.icon_container);
        Drawable standing =
                getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.test_circle);
         //assign background back to standing animation
        characterContainer.setBackgroundDrawable(standing);
    }

  }
```

As you can see, I put your 'down' code in a function, and your 'up' code in another function. Then, in the xml, add `android:onClick="onButtonDownClick"` to the down button. Do the same (except with an 'onButtonUpClick') to your up button. This will cause those functions to be called on click. It's important to note that those functions take a `View` as an argument.

Comment: Thanks for the help but I think you misunderstood my intentions. What I was trying to do was when my Up button was pressed it would move my image up 1 pixel and set the background as an animated .gif this would loop until the user released their finger from the button. Then the ACTION_UP code would run and swap the background back to an image of the character standing.

Comment: I've added some comments to my question to qualify. This is just a start. I'm going to copy the code for the other 3 buttons once finished but make them move the character left, right and down.

Comment: Ohh. My mistake, I did misunderstand you. Take a look at the second answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3784514/capture-button-release-in-android . I think that might do what you're trying to do.

Comment: And BTW, I see no reason why you can't keep that code in your onCreate function. (since it only needs to run once per the life of the activity)

Comment: Don't worry about it :) ye that's what I've tried to do in my code but when I click run I get back to my Null Pointer Exception ;)

Comment: when I was looking around for the answer people were saying the view.getLocationOnScreen can't be run inside onCreate() due to it needing the layout to be fully initialised before it can get the location. Or have I misunderstood?

Comment: Probably not. I haven't used that method, so you're probably right. To use one of those activity context functions, you just right a public void method, and call super.onWhatever() before doing anything else, as described here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html . As for your NullPointerException, I'm afraid I can't help you, sorry!

Comment: No Problem Thanks for your help anyway :) I might be onto something now though. I'll keep you posted.

Comment: Nope that didn't work still looking for an answer :) any help's appreciated