# Mono For Android: Button Down/Button Up Events

Tags: xamarin.android

I am working on my first app using Mono for Android.

I have one button on the screen.
I want and event(or some kind of notification) when it is pressed, and again when it is released. Not a simple click event (event firing only after button is released).

I'm sure that I am missing something obvious, but I cant seem to find any events that would solve the problem.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hope this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3784691/620138

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Aaron said, there is a `Touch` event on your button which you can use:

```
var button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.MyButton);
button.Touch += (s, e) =>
{
    if (e.Event.Action == MotionEventActions.Down)
    {
        //Do whatever you want on down here
    }
    if (e.Event.Action == MotionEventActions.Cancel || e.Event.Action == MotionEventActions.Up)
    {
        //Do whatever on up
    }
};
```