# Android: Strange gap between buttons

Tags: android

I am just beginning with Android. I am making a layout with buttons, but a very strange thing is happening — there is a small gap between them. Setting margin and padding to 0 is also not helping.

Here is my simple layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">



<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

It is looking like this:[image]

Comment: This is because Button 9.path drawable have small margin...

Comment: @dieter_h I tried setting margin to 0, it did not help.

Comment: I cannot check right now, but it is probably just the button's drawable which has padding in it (see there is padding at the top and bottom too). If you don't like it, draw you our 9-patch and set it as the background.

Comment: Look at [click Button YES]: http://android-holo-colors.com/

Comment: @GilVegliach I did not understand what you mean by "draw you our 9-patch and set it as the background”?

Comment: working with a height of 0dp and only relying on layout-weight is tricky. **Using a negative margin will eat up that space**

Comment: @Dizzy I meant use some software like photoshop to draw you 9-patch, then in code/xml use it as the background of the button

Comment: @GilVegliach then in the calculator app like this http://i.stack.imgur.com/vLDwX.jpg they are not using the default buttons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use android:background  to change the background of button. For example if you use `android:background = "#FFFFFF"`  your visual problem is fixed. In reality , there is no space between the buttons, their background creates an "illusion"

Comment: It is working, but the ripple effect on tap gets lost. Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: Use setOnClickListener and override onTouch methiod. Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/18848551/4805317 . From there you can set  whichever background you want when the button is pressed or not.

Comment: My i ask why you use so big buttons? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: i am going to make calculator. This is a small example. My app currently looks like this. http://i.stack.imgur.com/51nu5.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Make your own flat Button style with ripple effect [lollipop] and without it [pre-lollipop]:
https://gist.github.com/dmytrodanylyk/3513e42839ae4309d2b5

Comment: Wow, seems very complex to me. But thanks! I will check it out.