# Playing sound while button is pressed and stopping when released

Tags: android, soundpool

I want to make it so when a button is held down it starts playing sound and when released to stop. I know that there are a few people with the same problem but i didnt find a solution to the problem.

Here is my code:

```
 private ImageButton pad1, pad2, pad3, pad4, pad5, pad6, pad7, pad8, pad9, pad10, pad11, pad12;
SoundPool soundPool = null;
int sound1_id;
int sound2_id;
int sound3_id;
int sound4_id;
int sound5_id;
int sound6_id;
int sound7_id;
int sound8_id;
int sound9_id;
int sound10_id;
int sound11_id;
int sound12_id;

 pad1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.pad1);
    pad2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.pad2);
    pad3 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.pad3);
    pad4 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.pad4);
    pad5 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.pad5);
    pad6 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.pad6);
    pad7 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.pad7);
    pad8 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.pad8);
    pad9 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.pad9);
    pad10 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.pad10);
    pad11 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.pad11);
    pad12 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.pad12);


    soundPool = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
    sound1_id = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.p1, 1);
    sound2_id = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.p2, 1);
    sound3_id = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.p3, 1);
    sound4_id = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.p4, 1);
    sound5_id = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.p5, 1);
    sound6_id = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.p6, 1);
    sound7_id = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.p7, 1);
    sound8_id = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.p8, 1);
    sound9_id = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.p9, 1);
    sound10_id = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.p10, 1);
    sound11_id = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.p11, 1);
    sound12_id = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.p12, 1);


 public void onPad1Click(View view) {
    soundPool.play(sound1_id, (float) 0.5, (float) 0.5, 1, 0, 1.f);
}

public void onPad2Click(View view) {
    soundPool.play(sound2_id, (float) 0.5, (float) 0.5, 1, 0, 1.f);
}

public void onPad3Click(View view) {
    soundPool.play(sound3_id, (float) 0.5, (float) 0.5, 1, 0, 1.f);

}

public void onPad4Click(View view) {

    soundPool.play(sound4_id, (float) 0.5, (float) 0.5, 1, 0, 1.f);
}

public void onPad5Click(View view) {
    soundPool.play(sound5_id, (float) 0.5, (float) 0.5, 1, 0, 1.f);
}

public void onPad6Click(View view) {
    soundPool.play(sound6_id, (float) 0.5, (float) 0.5, 1, 0, 1.f);
}

public void onPad7Click(View view) {
    soundPool.play(sound7_id, (float) 0.5, (float) 0.5, 1, 0, 1.f);
}

public void onPad8Click(View view) {
    soundPool.play(sound8_id, (float) 0.5, (float) 0.5, 1, 0, 1.f);
}

public void onPad9Click(View view) {
    soundPool.play(sound9_id, (float) 0.5, (float) 0.5, 1, 0, 1.f);
}

public void onPad10Click(View view) {
    soundPool.play(sound10_id, (float) 0.5, (float) 0.5, 1, 0, 1.f);
}

public void onPad11Click(View view) {
    soundPool.play(sound11_id, (float) 0.5, (float) 0.5, 1, 0, 1.f);
}

public void onPad12Click(View view) {
    soundPool.play(sound12_id, (float) 0.5, (float) 0.5, 1, 0, 1.f);
}
```

}

Comment: This is a bit more tedious, but you could set a custom onTouchListener for each button and handle it there like in [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3784514/capture-button-release-in-android).
Or you could write one onTouchListener for each that determines which sound to play based on the view id.

Comment: So are you facing an issue with the code that you posted? If so, can you mention what is an issue?

Comment: no issue, the code works fine

Comment: i tried to add onTouchListener but it crashes. Here's what i did.

Comment: @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == event.ACTION_DOWN){
            soundPool.play(sound2_id, (float) 0.5, (float) 0.5, 1, 0, 1.f);
        }else soundPool.stop(0);
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

Comment: any ideas how i should do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the code below. Unfortunately I didn't have time to check if it works, but please comment here if you run into trouble, I'll help debug it.

```
import android.media.SoundPool;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

public class LoopSoundWhilePressing implements View.OnTouchListener {

private SoundPool soundPool;
private int soundId;
private int playedSoundId; //You need the id that's returned from SoundPool.play() to stop it later on
private boolean isPlaying;

public LoopSoundWhilePressing(SoundPool soundPool, int soundId) {
    this.soundPool = soundPool; //You give the soundPool and soundId for each instance.
    this.soundId = soundId; //The sound you will be playing
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    boolean handled = false;

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
            if(!isPlaying) {
                //The -1 will make it loop until we stop it on ActionUp
                playedSoundId = soundPool.play(soundId, (float) 0.5, (float) 0.5, 1, -1, 1.f);
                isPlaying = true;
            }
            handled = true;
            break;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
            if(isPlaying) {
                soundPool.stop(playedSoundId);
                isPlaying = false;
            }
            handled = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    return handled;
}
```

}