# How to detect a release of the button after a long press?

Tags: android, whatsapp, touch-event

Wanted to make a button release, have implemented `onLongClick()` and `onClick()` Listeners, they're working fine, but how to detect the **Release**. Actually wanted to create a button similar to **WhatsApp**'s audio record button, where if a short click or touch doesn't do anything, when held for a long time starts recording audio and upon release *stops* recording.

## Listeners

```
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                shortClick();
            }
        });

       btn.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
           @Override
           public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
               longClick();
               return true;
           }
       });
```

## Functions

```
 public void shortClick()
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Short click Cancel !!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    public void longClick()
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Long click started - Recording started !!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
```

So, need a function for release.

Comment: What do you mean? "release"

Comment: When we take away the touch after press and hold.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Capture button release in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3784514/capture-button-release-in-android)

Comment: Its a temporary solution @Siarhei because, It shows upon touch but Touch is not required, It should work like WhatsApp's MIC button. But yes it is working, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

here is the working code

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent KEvent) 
{
    int keyaction = KEvent.getAction();

    if(keyaction == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
    {
        int keycode = KEvent.getKeyCode();
        int keyunicode = KEvent.getUnicodeChar(KEvent.getMetaState() );
        char character = (char) keyunicode;

        System.out.println("DEBUG MESSAGE KEY=" + character + " KEYCODE=" +  keycode);
    }


    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(KEvent);
}
```